# 2 divs centered in html page

Tags: html, layout, center

I try to make a better layout of my webpage, so I want to place two divs in the center of my html page. I do not have access to my css file. Is it possible to center two divs on one page in html code without css?

This is my code:

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
<div style="; width: 100%;">
<h1 style="text-align: center;">This is Web Page Main tit</h1>

<div style="position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0px;
   width: 470px;
   height: 470px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: #828282">
<div><strong>Main Menu</strong></div>
  </div>

<div style="position: relative;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 auto;
   left: 0px;
   width: 470px;
   height: 470px;
   background-color: #828282">
<p>oke and Managerial Tutorials</p>
</div>

</div>
<div style="background-color: #b5dcb3; clear: both;">Here text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why in the world don't you have access to your CSS? This sounds too quirky to be anything but a stupid assignment, or similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two `<div>`'s next to each other aligned in the center of your page:

```
<center>
<div>
<div style="display: inline-block">
<!-- div 1 contents -->    
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block">
<!-- div 2 contents -->
</div>
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a CMS page but I have only access to a html file. I want two divs center next to each other. Is it possible? With your answer I can center each div on its own.

Comment: Here you go, edited the post to fit your requirements :D

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is a `<center>` html tag that you can try, placing it before and after `</center>` the divs you want centered, or if maybe you can still change your inline styles, get rid of the floats, clears, and positioning and add

```
div {
  margin: auto;
}
```

also you have a stray semicolon `<div style=";width: 100%;">`